# Find x and y so that two vectors are equal

Tags: vectors

I have part of the solution. I am not sure how to solve it. The condition and solution are in the photo.

[image]

Comment: C,d being equal means $c=d$, $k$ is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\vec a+y \vec b=(y+1)\vec a+(2-x) \vec b\implies x=y+1 ~\&~ y=2-x \implies x=3/2~ \& ~ y=1/2.$